Question about notation: arg z
I am reading the "Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions", and it has an odd notation that is not clearly explained. It will have, for example, a series expression with something like this
x -> inf,   |arg z| < pi
It is not at all clear what constraints are being placed here. Clearly, z is not being directly limited to -pi < z < pi. Possibly, it means to reduce z to the range 0 <= x < pi by adding / subtracting pi as necessary. But, this is never stated and is not clear. Perhaps it is standard notation, but if so, I have never seen it.
Does anyone know exactly what it means?
Thanks.

Most probably this is the argument of complex numbers.

Is there no page listing various notations used throughout the text just after the preface? The PDF I found does, but perhaps you only have access to an excerpt. It says$$\begin{array}{ll}\operatorname{Arg} z & \text{argument, } -\pi < \operatorname{Arg} z \le \pi \ \arg z & \operatorname{Arg}z \pm 2k\pi, k\in\Bbb N_0\end{array}$$

Isn't this simply a way of saying that $z$ must avoid the negative real axis? If it said $-\pi < \arg z \le \pi$ instead, then $z$ could be anywere, so that would be a meaningless condition. So what's being ruled out by requiring $-\pi < \arg z < \pi$ is just that $\arg z = \pi$.

Yes, it has the definition mentioned. However, that is very non-informative. From comments elsewhere it has to do with convergence. But, nothing explicit. To avoid negative values, 0 <= z would suffice. The complexity added by arg and Arg must be for something else. Likewise z -> inf is probably related to limits or convergence. No example code that I have found using one of these continued fractions appears to include anything in the tests, limitations, or formulas relating to these conditions. However, they may play a role in selecting a specific continued fraction for a specific purpose.

@MichaelLeeFinney: No, $z \ge 0$ wouldn't work, since $z$ is clearly a complex number here, and the relation “$\le$” is undefined for complex numbers.

@RandomVariable: Well, yes, $|\arg z| \le \pi - \delta$ means what it says, namely that you remove some sector around the negative real axis.

@MichaelLeeFinney: Regarding $x \to \infty$ (or $z \to \infty$ perhaps?), I would guess that they are talking about asymptotic series, but I don't have the book in question, so I can't tell for sure.

The book is clear about complex numbers, so that isn't it. And if Arg z is simply establishing a value range of (-pi, pi], then argz would be extending that range to all real numbers. There just isn't much, if any, clue as to what the definition itself means. This is the only book in which I have seen this notation, I had hoped that it is just something obscure that others knew about. Apparently, it is really obscure.

WolframAlpha has an "arg(x)" function. However, all it does is to return 0 when x > 0 and pi when x < 0. Clearly, that is not what is intended.
